# Only read a uploaded file with Sails Js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to upload a file as a buffer with utf-8 encoding parse to string substract a part of that string and thats it.

I don't want to save it on disk as currently does it sails with skipper.

https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this by uploading to a temp file and then reading from there. E.g.

```
// Since we don't provide any other 'opts' arguments to the upload
// method, it will upload our file to a temp directory
skipperFile.upload(function (err, uploadedFiles) {
// If no files were uploaded, respond with an error.
    if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) {
      return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded');
    }
    // Now that the file is uploaded, get the file descriptor
    var fd = uploadedFiles[0].fd;
    fs.readFile(fd, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        // Print the contents of the file as a string here
        // and do whatever other string processing you want
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been too late, but I still want to share these methods for others:

You can use `.reservoir()` method in [sails-hook-uploads](https://github.com/sailshq/sails-hook-uploads#usage) to achieve this.

Example:

```
const info = await sails.reservoir(uploadedFile, {encoding:'utf8'});
```

And the `info` should be:

```
[
  {
    contentBytes: 'data contents...',
    name: 'filename.txt',
    type: 'text/plain'
  }
]
```